# What kind of method/solver should I use for a system of coupled non linear equation involving n (>100) variables?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am solving a problem involving coupled non linear equations with the number of variables greater than 100.

I used Fsolve/lsqnonlin (MATLAB) for the problem, it worked well for smaller number of variables (around 20). However, with the increase in number of variables it does not converge to a solution.

```
function y2 = chec(p,n,ges,res) 
%n is the number of variables
% res is 1xn matrix with complex numbers
% ges is just a constant.
gaus=exp(-((-(n/2-0.5):(n/2-0.5)).^2)/9000);
S=gaus.*exp(1i*p);
M=S'*S;
y2=zeros(n,1);
for k = 2:n
   cv = sum(diag(M,k-1))-res(k);
   if(k<n)
       y2(2*(k-lm)+1)=real(cv);
       y2(2*(k-lm)+2)=imag(cv);
   elseif(k==n)
       y2(2*(k-lm)+1)=imag(log(sum(diag(M,k-1)))-log(aucrr(k)));
       y2(2*(k-lm)+2)=p(n)-ges;
   end
end
%%% function ends here %%%
[z,fval] = fsolve(@(x) chec(x,n,ges,res),rand(1,n));
```

Comment: Please provide information on what you already have tried.  Also please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question complete.

Comment: I think I  already told the thing which I have done, but if you need the code it's added now.

Comment: It may be a non-convex problem, try using a global optimizer with multiple start points.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html

Comment: Providing explicit gradients may help.